# Merging multiple pdf files

Tags: pdf, blob.topdf

I was just wondering if anyone has created a method to merge 2 or more pdf files into one single pdf using Apex. I basically want to give the option to users by uploading or selecting few different pdf files in an apex page and then generate single pdf with any order they want. is it possible to do that?